# How to use the RibbonTab interface in c#?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, ribbon, excel-addins

I am working in excel VSTO add-in.

In excel, having built-in tabs, groups, and controls in the ribbon.

I am trying to use the `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon RibbonTab` interface.

But I am not able to use this interface.

```
private RibbonTab hometab;

public bool ShowVisibleView(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
     hometab.Name = "View";

     var groupList = hometab.Groups;

     return true;
 }
```

Here, `hometab` comes as null. So, I can't able to set the value for `Name` property in `RibbonTab`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to get list of groups present under built-in tabs in c#.

Comment: See [Office 2016 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745). Also at runtime you can use Accessibility API. There is no trivial way for getting built-in groups programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

The ribbon tab should be instantiated first. There are two main ways for creating a custom ribbon UI in Visual Studio:

- [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-ribbon-xml?view=vs-2022)
- [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using the Ribbon Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-the-ribbon-designer?view=vs-2022)

You can't also manage built-in controls on the ribbon. The best what you could do is to repurpose built-in controls or build the ribbon from scratch.

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) is described in depth in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Read more about repurposing built-in controls in the [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb462633(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.